# android: how to make a page navgation bar

Tags: android, button

im making an app that interacs with a webservie which then gets data from an external database.  when i ask for data from my db i filter it by for example 25 record per page so that i doesnt take too long to get the data. (becasue the db has lots of records). i want to make a page navigaton bar so that i can go to the successive 25 records and so on. Also because if i load all the records on a listView the user would have to sroll down for ages if he wanted something from the end.
how do i make this bar? any suggestions?

i though of making like 2 small buttons (next and prev) at the bottom of the page and when you click on next, the button asks the webservice (through http request url) to get the successive records and so on. is it possible or is there a better and/or simpler way?

any help is much apreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common practice I have seen is adding a load more button to the end of a list.  Basically just make a custom listview [here is a tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) on how to do that.  Then just put a button, or imageview or whatever you want as the last item at all times.  When the user selects the bottom item then load more items.

A quick sudo code for adding a button at the end of the list

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(position == size-1){
        return (new Button());
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i add a button at the bottom of a list view?

Comment: mikeIsrael, i made it with with actual buttons (prev and next) and a textView to show the page number in my xml file and then from the activity i use them.

Comment: @HassanSamii alright, well if you ever change your mind and try this implementation (I recommend it for Android because Google seem to like it) let me know if you need help implementing it.  Good luck.